# identify at least 1 column having a value + MVC Linq

Tags: linq

I'm starting to work with MVC, but i'm struck with one logic with LinQ query. I have attached the image which explains the scenario and logic. Kindly help me with linq query

```
Column A    Column B    Column C
Test A        A1         C1
Test A        A2         C2
Test A        A4         C3
Test A        A5    
Test B        B1    
Test B        B2         C7
Test B        B3    
Test B        B4         C9
Test C        D1    
Test C        D2
```

Count of (Column A with atleast minimum 1 Column B has Column C value)/(Total of Column A)

```
Test A  3/5=    0.6
Test B  2/4=    0.5
Test C  0/2=    0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that :

Not clear what's impact of column B, by the way...

```
yourTable.GroupBy(m => m.ColumnA)
.Select(m=> new {
   key = m.Key,
   count = m.Count(x => x.ColumnC == null) / (decimal)m.Count()
});
```